# Light only half of the LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno, neopixel

How can I only let half of the LEDs light up,
for example, LED 1 on, LED 2 off, LED 3 on...and so on.

I did it this way
(this example fades also all LEDs on and off)

```c
   int x = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i > -1; i = i + x){
      leds[0] = CRGB(i,0,0);
      leds[1] = CRGB(0,i,0);
      leds[2] = CRGB(i,0,0);
      leds[3] = CRGB(0,i,0);
      Serial.println(i);
      FastLED.show();
      if (i >= 55) x = -1;             // switch direction at peak
      delay(10);
   }
```

but that is not so nice if you have 100 LEDs or so.

Comment: Change `int x = 1;` to `int x = 2;`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about neopixel but as a general coding practice if you want to do something for every other object, you use the modulus operator like so

```
if(i % 2 == 0)
{
  //i is even
  //off
}
else
{
  //i is odd
  //on
}
```

So just wrap your current for loop in another one and to the above with the iterating variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i > -1; i = i + x){
     // using modulo
     if(i % 2 == 0){
     leds[i] = CRGB(i,0,0)}else{
     leds[i] = CRGB(0,i,0);}

      Serial.println(i);
      FastLED.show();
      if (i >= 55) x = -1;             // switch direction at peak
      delay(10);
   }
```

or

```
int x = 2;
   for (int i = 0; i > -1; i = i + x){
     leds[i] = CRGB(i,0,0);

      Serial.println(i);
      FastLED.show();
      if (i >= 55) x = -2;             // switch direction at peak
      delay(10);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is, for the most part, exactly what others have said. However, nobody has managed to actually use a `for` loop properly; they've carried forward your inefficiencies for some unknown reason.

The whole point of a `for` loop is to execute a block of code a predetermined number of times. In your code, you create a loop that loops for a ridiculous length (65,536 times) but each time checks how many loops there have been.

Once the `for` loop has been constructed properly there are two approaches:

```
int NUMBER_LEDS = 100;      // you only ever have to change this
                            // if the number of LEDs change - and it's really
                            // easy to find if you put it at the start of
                            // your code.

for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_LEDS; x++)
{
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        leds[x] = CRGB(x,0,0);
    else
        leds[x] = CRGB(0,x,0);
    Serial.println(x);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(10);
}
```

The above code is fine if you just want two LED subsets. If you want more than two, you can use a `switch/case` statement:

```
int NUMBER_LEDS = 100;      // you only ever have to change this
                            // if the number of LEDs change - and it's really
                            // easy to find if you put it at the start of
                            // your code.
int NUMBER_SETS = 4;        // this will give four groups.


for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_LEDS; x++)
{
    switch (x % NUMBER_SETS)
    {
        case (0):
        {
            leds[x] = CRGB(0,0,0);
            break;
        }
        case (1):
        {
            leds[x] = CRGB(x,0,0);
            break;
        }
        case (2):
        {
            leds[x] = CRGB(0,x,0);
            break;
        }
        case (3):
        {
            leds[x] = CRGB(0,0,x);
            break;
        }
    }
    Serial.println(x);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(10);
}
```

You don't have to write a `case` block for every outcome of `x%2`; you might want a certain group of LEDs to stay on for two iterations, for example. More information on `switch/case` can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/), towards the bottom of the page.

I recommend you read this article on [Operators in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/), starting from "Compound Assignement". It helps make code more readable and can considerably decrease the amount of typing you have to do - `i = i + 1` neatly becomes `i++`.